# Existe servidor localhost pago?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, localhost

Pesquisei na internet e não achei nada relacionado. Quero montar um servidor localhost, para testar minhas aplicações.

Já testei Xampp, Wampserver EasyPHP e outros...

- Existe algum sistema que seja pago?
- A forma correta de se falar é "Servidor localhost", "HTTP Server", ou outro nome?

Resolvi buscar um sistema pago para acabar com esse problema de ficar mexendo em na configuração, um sistema completo e com recursos visuais facilitam o dia a dia e posso me dedicar a outras coisas.

Comment: localhost: igual ao 127.0.0.1, aponta para a sua própria máquina. HTTP Server: geralmente roda na porta 80 ou 8080, são coisas bem diferentes. Alguns HTTP Servers conhecidos são o Apache, IIS, Ngix. Xampp tem a instalação do Apache, PHP e MySQL juntos, prefiro instalar os mesmos individualmente.

Comment: Procure por 'servidor HTTP' ou 'servidor WEB'. nesse caso verifique nos recursos disponíveis: Interface gráfica e suporte a PHP (ou fast CGI). Se não me engano, o php hoje em dia vem com um servidor web embutido, não precisando instalar mais nada. O uso de um servidor web mesmo é só pra produção, melhor usar o servidor embutido pra desenvolvimento. Eu não sou programador PHP, Programo em outras linguagens e muitos frameworks que trabalho vem com servidores web embutidos e eu não perco tempo configurando nada

Comment: Se você quer tempo e dinheiro não é problema então instala um visual studio, cria um projeto asp.net MVC e aperta play, vai está rodando em um servidor IIS deles. Mas o tempo que você perde aprendendo a configurar os que você colocou aí é um tempo que você perde uma única vez e leva o conhecimento para a vida. Acho que vale a pena aprender.

Comment: @Ricardo uma dúvida paralela. Visual studio é melhor que o Dreamweaver?

Comment: Para dizer o melhor tem que existir uma necessidade, todos tem vantagens e desvantagens e por isso depende do que você quer fazer. Se você conseguir editar a pergunta e dizer mais sobre os seus projetos, o tamanho, tecnologias, etc seria mais fácil opinar.

Comment: Você quer uma hospedagem é isso? existem algumas alternativas gratuitas com algumas limitações.

Answer (score 1):

Na verdade, o que você quer dizer é um servidor web. Estritamente falando, o Xampp não é um servidor web propriamente dito. Ele é uma aplicação que tem vários servidores embutidos. Além do apache, ele usa o mysql (além de outros). O EasyPHP funciona do mesmo jeito.

Talvez, você queira uma aplicação paga com essas características (que contenha um servidor web, um servidor de banco de dados, tudo embutido). É isso, certo?

Até existe (exemplo do IIS da Microsoft), mas eu acredito que esses dois que você mencionou são os mais simples de usar. Mexer em configuração vai ser preciso em qualquer um (pago ou não). O que eu sugiro é pegar um tutorial (ou vídeo aula, fica a seu critério) e estudar como funciona. No início, precisa ter paciência para aprender mesmo, mas depois as coisas passam a funcionar com mais fluidez.

EDIT: Dê uma olhada neste vídeo sobre o EasyPHP: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zn3NF3T55Tc

Talvez, essa busca sobre o xampp possa te ajudar: https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=video+aula+xampp

Answer (score 0):

Como os colegas já falaram, programas como Xampp, Wamp e etc são 'pacotões' de programas como PHP, MySQL e Apache. Destes o Wamp é o que possui a interface mais amigável, basta acessar o http://localhost

Porém.... configurar servidores é uma coisa que é inevitável, mesmo que haja um sysadmin na sua equipe de trabalho que cuide disso, vocês vão conversar sobre configurações de servidores #fato

Pelo visto você deve estar começando a programar para web agora, então aproveite para aprender sobre servidores web também.

Boa sorte!